Resolving Persistent Timeout Issue
I'm currently dealing with an issue in an older project running on JBoss + Java 7. I'm using calls through a WSDL file there, but in case the remote service is unavailable, I get a very long timeout (around a minute). I've tried to change this by adding properties, but none of the properties I added for this timeout seem to respond.
I'm receiving this error:
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:79)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:339)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:182)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.connect(SSLSocketImpl.java:625)
    at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:175)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:432)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:527)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.<init>(HttpsClient.java:264)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.New(HttpsClient.java:367)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:191)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:933)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:177)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1092)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:250)
    at org.jboss.remoting.transport.http.HTTPClientInvoker.useHttpURLConnection(HTTPClientInvoker.java:288)

My code (slightly modified for project sensitivity):
import javax.xml.ws.BindingProvider;


MyRemoteService port = svcService.getBasicHttpEndpoint();

BindingProvider bp = (BindingProvider) port;
bp.getRequestContext().put("com.sun.xml.ws.connect.timeout", 3000);
bp.getRequestContext().put("com.sun.xml.ws.request.timeout", 5000);

I also tried other sets of properties recommended here:
bp.getRequestContext().put("com.sun.xml.internal.ws.connect.timeout", 3000);
bp.getRequestContext().put("com.sun.xml.internal.ws.request.timeout", 5000);

or
bp.getRequestContext().put("javax.xml.ws.client.connectionTimeout", 3000);
bp.getRequestContext().put("javax.xml.ws.client.receiveTimeout", 5000);

None of that worked. I also tried setting system properties, but that didn't work either.
sun.net.client.defaultConnectTimeout=3000
sun.net.client.defaultReadTimeout=10000

Any further advice on how I can set this timeout to make it work?
Thanks for help
